# How to react on empty Lists using wildcards as type?

Tags: java, list, wildcard

I wanna set a List in a class using a wildcard as type:

```
 public List<?> setList(List<?> list){
      this.list = list;
 }
```

But I only will accept some types of the List elements. The example contains only the String approach but I will accept String, Double or Integer f.e..

I know this approach:

```
 public void setList(List<?> list){
     if(!list.isEmpty())
         if(list.get(0).getClass().equals(String.class))
              this.list = list;
         else
              throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     else 
         // what to do?
 }
```

If the List isn't empty I can check the first elements class. If it's of the String.class I will set the List, otherwise an Exception will be thrown.

But how should I react if the List is empty? Because AFAIK I can't check the type of the wildcard because of type erasure. So, I can't instanciate a empty List.

Should I just do `this.list = null;`? Or should I only accept not empty Lists and throw an Exception if it's empty? I appreciate any suggestion. Because this code will be reused and the guy who works with it should be informed about what happens.

Comment: Why not use `Object` as a type instead of the wildcard?

Comment: @Bart Well, this would lead in Lists which can be contain every possible Type at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer directly to your question: there will be no problem with an empty list.

Because of type erasure there is no difference between List<String>, List<Double> or simple List at runtime.

You can even fool the compiler and do things like

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("foo");
List rawList = stringList;
rawList.add(42);
List<Integer> integerList = rawList;
```

having three references to the same list with different treatment only by the compiler. (You will get some warnings dependend on your compiler settings, but that's all.)

If you want to check the consistency at runtime, you have to check every single member of the list

```
public <T> void setList(List<T> list, Class<T> clazz) {
    for (T t : list) {
        if(!clazz.equals(t.getClass())) {
            throw new YourPreferedKindOfException();
        }
    }
    this.list = list;
}
```

(check for null arguments omitted)

Suitable exception could be IllegalArgumentException, called e.g.

```
setList(stringList, String.class);
```

To be realy sure at runtime you have to copy the list, because your function got the list as reference and the content of it can be modified outside your function later.

Comment: Nice infos here! Thanks for that. I'll have a close look at this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I have three approaches here:

- **SIMPLE GENERIC APPROACH**

You have to parametrize the class holding the list. By creating a new instance with a specified generic type. That would be a type-safe approach.

```
public class ListHolder<T> {

    private List<T> list;

    public void setList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListHolder<String> sl = new ListHolder<String>();
        sl.setList(new ArrayList<String>());

        ListHolder<Double> dl = new ListHolder<Double>();
        dl.setList(new ArrayList<Double>());
    }
}
```

- **DYNAMIC PERMISSION BASED APPROACH**

Here we populate a set with classes that are allowed.

```
public class ListHolder {
    private Set<Class<?>> allowed = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    private List<?> list;

    public <T> void setList(List<T> list) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            // problem is we can't check type here. Exception would be better
            list = Collections.<T> emptyList();
        } else {
            Class<?> clazz = list.get(0).getClass();
            if (allowed.contains(clazz)) {
                this.list = list;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type "
                        + clazz.getSimpleName() + " not allowed!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void allowClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        allowed.add(clazz);
    }
}
```

- **STATIC PERSMISSION BASED APPROACH**

Here the checking takes place at compile time.

```
public class ListHolder {

    private List<?> list;

    public static final Allowed<String> STRING = new Allowed<String>();
    public static final Allowed<Double> DOUBLE = new Allowed<Double>();

    public <T> void setList(List<T> list, Allowed<T> permission) {
        if (permission == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Permission is null!");
        this.list = list;
        if (list == null) // if you don't want list to be null
            this.list = Collections.<T>emptyList(); // added type parameter to make it clearer for reader
        // ...compiler does that implicitly
    }

    private static class Allowed<T> {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListHolder l = new ListHolder();

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        l.setList(strings, ListHolder.STRING);
        l.setList(doubles, ListHolder.DOUBLE);
        //l.setList(integers, ListHolder.DOUBLE); Does not even compile
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay! If some of my thoughts are unclear, just ask. I didn't write too much, but I tried to make the code talk for itself.

Comment: Because the dynamic approach is quite the same as my code, which exception should I throw if the List is empty? Because IMO this is the way to go for me. And it makes me think if I'm on the right way in general.

Comment: With the dynamic approach you can't set an empty list - of any type. The first approach has the disadvantage that you would have to create a new instance for each type. I'd prefer the last one. The person that needs to work with your class, would know at compile time, if he used an incompatible type, also he does not have to catch any exception at runtime (...the null is no big deal). And yes, the method is more verbose. But you could hide the internals with a helper method, e.g. `setStringList(List<String> list) { setList(list, ListHolder.STRING); }`

Comment: I know that no empty List can be instanciated, that's why I wanna throw an Exception, but which one?

Comment: Yes, but you could allow empty lists with the latter approach, and no exception are thrown. The NPE is obvious, is just thrown if you call the method with `setList(anylist, null)`. But if you want to stick to your approach / dynamic approach - I guess `IllegalArgumentException` would be appropiate in that case, but you would have to document it carefully in the java doc. And of course more test cases would have to be written, since the approach is dynamic the failures come out during runtime...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36987/discussion-between-steve-benett-and-mike)